# Euler's circut / path undirected graph in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, algorithm, graph, tree, cytoscape.js

Today I'm starting with Cytoscape and I made some random graphs, now I need to find Eulers Circuit and Path in it.

Does the Cytoscape have a built in function that will help me reach that?

I have heard that can be used recurrent DFS postorder to find it, but I'm not that advanced in programming to develop it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer to the question:** 
No, cytoscape.js doesn't have this feature as a built in function. Though cytoscape.js has some very good traversal algorithms like [dfs](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.breadthFirstSearch), [bfs](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.depthFirstSearch), [dijkstra](http://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.dijkstra) and more, but these are no good for eulers circles.

**Solution:**

You will either have to implement you own solution to this problem or find some online(which you probably will).

**My advice:**

Search for a javascript/jquery solution for the algorithm and try it out with cytoscape.js, if you get stuck on the way, post a question with your current approach and a minimal example and the community will probably sort it out with you.